# How to create Vue.js modal with dynamically generated IDs?

Tags: vue.js

New to VueJS and a bit lost. I have a table that is taking an array of objects and generating each row for display.

For each row, there should be a button. When the button is clicked, a modal should display with specific text from that row.

I am generating the modals like this:

```
<td style="width:185px;margin:auto;vertical-align:middle;">
   <b-button v-bind:v-b-modal="'Modal' + d.Id" size="sm">Select Associate</b-button>
   <b-modal v-bind:id="'Modal' + d.Id" title="Primary Associate Selected" hide-footer>
        Click "Copy and Create" to copy {{ d.Name}}'s phone number and to create an assignment.
        <b-button
              class="mt-3"
              variant="outline-primary"
              block
              @click="$bvModal.hide('Modal' + d.Id), copyPhoneAndCreateAssignment(d)"
        >Create Assignment</b-button>
        <b-button class="mt-3" block @click="$bvModal.hide('Modal' + d.Id)">Cancel</b-button>
   </b-modal>
</td>
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to generate dynamic IDs. v-bind:id="'Modal' + d.Id" doesn't seem to work properly. Modals aren't popping up with the code I have above.

If I set it manually, the modals will display, but so will every other modal with the same ID... :( Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: you could make only one modal and do something like @click="dataToShow = d" and in the modal you take dataToShow.name and whatever else you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, never mind. I figured it out lol.

The b-button can take a dynamic Id if it's set as:

```
<b-button v-b-modal="'SecondaryModal' + d.Id" size="sm">Select Firm</b-button>
```

And the b-modal should have its ID set as:

```
<b-modal :id="'SecondaryModal' + d.Id" title="Secondary Firm Selected" hide-footer>
```